# How to unhide icon on clicking icon on same row? Asp.net MVC Angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-4

I want to unhide icon on the click edit icon on the same row in a table row.

these edit and save icon generate according to the records,

my code is,

```
<td>
   <a ng-click="vm.Select(Survey.Id)" title="{{ 'Select' | translate }}">
     <i class="fa fa-edit fa-1x"></i>
   </a>
</td>
<td>
   <a ng-click="vm.Update(Survey.Id)" title="{{ 'Update Visit' | translate }}">
     <i class="fa fa-save fa-1x"></i>
   </a>
</td>
```

when I click on icon having "select" title only icon with the title "update visit" unhide that is on the same row

Hopes for your suggestions thanks

Comment: You can do this by ```ng-show``` and ```ng-hide``` depends on the requirement . So you show ```update``` and ```cancel``` option when you click on ```select``` and similarly when you select ```update``` or ```cancel``` hide these two and show ```select```

Comment: @sai i have set id and style visibility hidden for each td on click button how can i change its visibility true

Comment: you have some pre defined directives in angular js [ https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-show ] check this for reference

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic demo to play around your code using `ng-show` and `ng-hide` . You can check this and tweak your code

```js
angular.module('App', []).controller('CrudCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.Profiles = [{
        name: "gede",
        country: "indonesia",
        editable: false
      },
      {
        name: "made",
        country: "thailand",
        editable: false
      }
    ];

    $scope.entity = {}

    $scope.edit = function(index) {
      $scope.entity = $scope.Profiles[index];
      $scope.entity.index = index;
      $scope.entity.editable = true;
    }

    $scope.delete = function(index) {
      $scope.Profiles.splice(index, 1);
    }

    $scope.save = function(index) {
      $scope.Profiles[index].editable = false;

    }

    $scope.add = function() {
      $scope.Profiles.push({
        name: "",
        country: "",
        editable: true
      })
    }
  }
]);
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

body {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 10px;
}

table tr td span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="CrudCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Country</td>
        <td><span ng-click="add()">Add New</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="profile in Profiles">
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="profile.name" ng-show="profile.editable">
          <span ng-hide="profile.editable">{{ profile.name }}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="profile.country" ng-show="profile.editable">
          <span ng-hide="profile.editable">{{ profile.country }}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span ng-click="edit($index)" ng-hide="profile.editable">Edit</span>
          <span ng-click="save($index)" ng-show="profile.editable">Save</span>
          <span ng-click="delete($index)"> | Delete</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```